# Snippet causing page to not save

Tags: javascript, servicemax

I have a snippet made to execute on Before save/update which causes the page to be stuck loading. Its just a

```
console.log("js snippet");
return;
```

I get the expected output, but the page gets stuck loading and will not save after the code executes. The page works fine if there is no snippet or if there is a syntax error in the snippet.

Comment: What if you remove the `return;` ? Wouln't expect it to make a difference, but returning nothing it might be the same as returning `false` which may prevent further execution.

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to clarify the context of this JavaScript, such as Visualforce, Lightning Web Component, Lighting Aura Component, and include more details of the problem? You've tagged your question `servicemax`, which doesn't typically fall in our scope at Salesforce Stack Exchange.

Comment: Or return true. Depends on the caller